# a nuitka created exe crashes immediately without error information

Tags: python, nuitka

I am trying to create a standalone installer using nuitka. I used the following command:

```
python -m nuitka --standalone --mingw64 --show-progress --windows-disable-console --recurse-all -- 
nofollow-import-to=sklearn --plugin-enable=qt-plugins --enable-plugin=numpy=matplotlib --plugin- 
enable=numpy --plugin-enable=numpy=scipy rs_main.py
```

It took some time, but besides a few warnings (which are at the bottom) it all seemed to work. However when I start the exe nothing really happens. It sort of crashes immediately. I started both by clicking and from the command line but I am not getting any error information.

Is there any error information available somewhere? All I can do is try to solve below warnings but I am no really sure that is the problem and I do not know how I should solve them.

```
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\PIL\Image.py:406' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include-plugin- 
files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\backend_managers.py:356' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '-- 
include-plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\core\function_base.py:497' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '-- 
include-plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\lib\utils.py:393' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include- 
plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\lib\utils.py:847' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include- 
plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\lib\utils.py:905' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include- 
plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\__init__.py:11' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include-plugin- 
files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py:160' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '--include- 
plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py:3041' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '-- 
include-plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\__init__.py:58' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '-- 
include-plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:306' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '-- 
include-plugin-files'.
Nuitka:WARNING:Unresolved '__import__' call at 'C:\Users\hillebr\Miniconda3\envs\pristina\lib\site- 
packages\sqlalchemy\sql\type_api.py:612' may require use of '--include-plugin-directory' or '-- 
include-plugin-files'.
```

Comment: can you run the exe from the cmd line?  It should print any errors out there

Comment: I tried that. There is no information